# Saving Template after VBA references are added

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some code which adds the VBA references i require for using Access. (it checks if the user already has them included).

This all works fine. My problem is when i then go to close word I am prompted to save the Acronym Tools template (Where the macro that this code is stored). Is it possible to do this programtically so that is it done as soon as references are added and the user does not see it happening?

The code i use:

```
If Not isReferenceLoaded("Access") Then
        MsgBox ("Access Object library not found, the script will now attempt to find the library for you.")

        'Ensure access library is included so database actions can be done
        ID.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACC.OLB"

        MsgBox ("Access Object library added")

    End If

    If Not isReferenceLoaded("DAO") Then
        MsgBox ("DAO library not found, the script will now attempt to find the library for you.")

        'Ensure access library is included so database actions can be done
        ID.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\ACEDAO.DLL"

        MsgBox ("DAO library added")
    End If
```

The function to see if reference is loaded:

```
Private Function isReferenceLoaded(referenceName As String) As Boolean
    Dim xRef As Variant
    For Each xRef In ThisDocument.VBProject.References
        isReferenceLoaded = (xRef.Name = referenceName) Or isReferenceLoaded
    Next xRef
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>If you don't want to save the document with the updated references (they'll be remade next time the doc is open, I guess) add to your Document object (supposedly named `ThisDocument`) the following subroutine:</s>

```
Private Sub Document_Close()

        ThisDocument.Saved = True

End Sub
```

This would inhibit the save-check only for ThisDocument. Add a `Call ThisDocument.Save` statement at the beginning, if you *do* want to save. However, I would count on the users to save their changes... but that's a matter of strategy, please do as you wish.

**Nota Bene:** Do not forget to save after adding the function: you'll lose the changes if you forget to; Word will ignore your changes because it was just instructed to do so by the function. :-)

Comment: I am not trying to save the new blank document. I have a template saved in the word startup folder. Because most people in the company do not have access I need to specifically add the VBA references to the Access objects. My code does that fine. but when you go to close word it asks to save changes to the template in the startup folder as well as the open document.

Comment: So, if you override the Document_Close() function of your template with the code above, it still asks for saving the template? That's odd... What version of Office you use?

Comment: The thing is I want to save that change to the template so i don't need to load the vba access references each time. What I don't understand is how i use the regular saving options to save a template which is loaded by the startup not by me during the script

Comment: You may use `Save` like for any other document. Suppose your template project name is "MyDot". Suppose that the name of the MS Word Object inside is called "MyDoc" (you may see their true names in your VBEditor, in the "Project Explorer" window). Then, to save them after modifications, just `Call MyDot.MyDoc.Save`.

Comment: :D :D bingo, thank you very much that was exactly what i needed. I knew it must use the regular save functions but couldn't get it to work myself.